# Como criar um menu hamburger com uma MainPage herdando de TabbedPage?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em criar um menu `hamburger` porque minha `MainPage` herda de `TabbedPage`. Existe uma forma de se fazer isso com uma `TabbedPage`? Para criar esse menu, normalmente criamos duas páginas novas(`ContentPage`) e passamos a `MainPage` para herdar de `MasterDetailPage` e no construtor da `MainPage` fazemos:

```
this.Master = new Master();
this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Detail());
```

essa seria a clássica forma. Porém como minha `MainPage` herda de `TabbedPage` não consigo implementar isso. Se remover a `TabbedPage`, perco a navegabilidade da página por **Tabs**. Nem sei se há como chama uma `TabbedPage` de dentro da `MainPage` como `MasterDetailPage`. Abaixo a minha `MainPage`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Operacional.Views"
            x:Class="Operacional.Views.MainPage">


    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Indicadores">
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_about.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Indicadores />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Paineis">
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:PaineisPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

e o code behind da mesma

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MainPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);

            //this.Master = new Master();

           // NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty. = Color.Gray;
        }
    }
```

se eu conseguisse deixar a `MainPage` livre e rodar uma outra página dentro, também resolveria, mas a questão é: Tem como criar um menu com uma MainPage herdando de TabbedPage?

Uso **Net Standard(Xamarin.Forms)**

**EDIT1**

Fiz esse código dentro da MainPage

```
public MainPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);

            Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailPage
            {
                Master = new Master(), ==>> aqui o erro
                Detail = new TabbedPage
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new NavigationPage(new Indicadores()),
                        new NavigationPage(new PaineisPage())
                    }
                }
            };

            // NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty. = Color.Gray;

        }
```

e pego esse erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:

```
 Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailPage
                {
                    Master = new Master(),
                    Detail = new TabbedPage
                    {
                        Children =
                    {
                        new NavigationPage(new Indicadores()){ Title = "Indicadores"},
                        new NavigationPage(new PaineisPage()){ Title = "Painéis"}
                    }
                    }
                };
```

e passe a `MainPage` para MasterDetailPage. Dessa forma consegui criar o menu.